# Use IText writer to check if pdf is opened

Tags: itext, corrupt

I am looking for a way to check if a PDF file stored on a shared netwerk is open by another process by user X.

My searches were not satisfying and I am now trying to use the iText7 PDFwriter to check if the PDF is in use. And this works but when the PDF is NOT in use my theory fails.

If the PDF is not in use the closing the writer corrupts my PDF.

My code:

```
Public Function IsOpen(ByVal oPath As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim oWriter As New PdfWriter(oPath)
        oWriter.Close()
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return True
    End Try
End Function
```

So my question is. Can I close the PDFwriter without doing anything to the PDF. Cancel the write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can write the same content to the file rather than cancel the writing.

Firstly let's write the pdf to memory:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourcePath), new PdfWriter(baos));
    pdfDocument.close();
```

Then let's rewrite the file with the bytes stored in memory:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(baos.toByteArray()), new ReaderProperties()),
            new PdfWriter(sourcePath), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
    pdfDoc.close();
```

The side effect: during rewriting the pdf may be optimised by iText a bit.